# Maven tries to download older version of maven-clean-plugin and gives 'failed to parse plugin descriptor' error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying build my project using Maven in Eclipse. I have an existing repository which has all required JARs, but still Eclipse tries to download a lower version (2.4.1) of maven-clean-plugin-2.5 and throws the below error in log.

**[WARNING]** `Checksum validation failed, expected c3ad1d9e5ee3daeac15f8e18e987a214bbaa343a but is 541613ad92f57707672f5989d37cf83ae9f3f31b for`

**[ERROR]**

```
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 (C:\Users\577103\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.4.1\maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar): error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checksum warning indicates that the downloaded jar is most likely corrupt. Try deleting the plugin folder in your local repository. Maven will download it again when it is needed (run maven clean and/or package). Also check that you are referring to the desired version of the plugins in your pom.xml.

Comment: I am new Maven. below is my pom.xml. Can you please tell me where I have referred the older version or where I have to?

Comment: I am not able to paste the pom.xml. But in my pom.xml, I already have no entry for maven-clean-plugin. But why it is looking for particular version(2.4.1)?

Comment: Btw, your comment was helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Why version 2.4.1 was chosen depends on various factors, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12315746/741249 for an explanation.