# Should I indicate dependency versions in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Most examples from the Internet on Java do not indicate the version of the dependencies in  tags. Should I indicate dependency versions in production pom.xml file?

If I do not indicate the version, where then is the number of the dependency version is stored of my project in GIT repo?

Comment: You should always define the versions (release versions!) of your dependencies and also of your plugins.. (pluginManagement) etc.

Comment: Is this by chance a Spring Boot project? Because the SB starter parent includes another parent that defines many, many version numbers. Other parent poms may do the same thing, specifying dependency management details for dependencies. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316462/636009) and try `mvn help:effective-pom` to see the versions maven is finding for your pom.

Answer (score 3):

I add a third answer because I think the other two missed the true meaning of your question.  Let us know what's the right one for your needs.

In Maven it is **mandatory** to specify the version number of each dependency.  If you see a block like this one:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

without an explicit `<version>` tag, it means that the version is specified *elsewhere*, in a `<dependencyManagement>` block.  Tipically this block is in the root pom of the Maven project or in an external parent of the root pom.
`spring-boot-starter-parent` is a well-known example of external parent that provides a `<dependencyManagement>` block.

See also the Maven documentation about [dependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management).

Answer (score -1):

indicate a version -> use a spesific version.
...
doesn't indicate a version -> will try to fetch latest available version.

This might be tempting to think (wouldn't it be best to always take latest?)
but it might occur weird bugs over the time.
Imagine not entering to a project for two years and now anything is a mess and you don't know which part makes the mess.

Comment: Can you explain this part: `use a spesific version doesn't indicate a version -> will try to fetch latest available version.`?

Answer (score -1):

This is somewhat of an opinion-based question, but here's opinion:

If you don't specify a version, then there is no actual record in your version control repo of what version you get. I believe that you would get the latest version each time it is resolved. For production apps, this would, IMHO, not be acceptable at all.

You can specify just a major version, or major/minor or major/minor/patch.

Theoretically, it *should* be safe to specify major and minor versions to make sure that the version that you get it compatible with your code.

But, if you want to be really sure that your code and the library are entirely compatible, then you would specify the patch version as well.

I tend to use just the major version number during initial development, and then lock down to the patch version for initial production deployment after verifying that all tests still pass.

You can then upgrade individual library versions later, if you become aware of security updates or new features that you want to use, again, after fully testing them.